# Roundcube Installer 404 Error (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, php, roundcube

I am trying to install Roundcube for my website. This is on my hosting server and I am currently following this tutorial:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/install-roundcube-webmail-ubuntu-16-04-nginx-mariadb-php7

I’ve gotten to the end of step 4, using TTLS. When I go to step 5, trying to visit `mail.stackexchange.com/installer` I am met with an Nginx 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out, so I am hoping someone else can chime in! This is my first time using Nginx instead of Apache2

**Server**

Ubuntu 16.0.4 running Nginx and Gunicorn for a django application. My install directory of Roundcube is /usr/share/nginx/roundcubemail

**Roundcube configuration**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mail.your-domain.com;
  return 301 https://mail.your-domain.com/$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name mail.your-domain.com;
  root /usr/share/nginx/roundcubemail/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.your-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.your-domain.com/privkey.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/roundcube.error;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/roundcube.access;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  location ~ ^/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ ^/(bin|SQL)/ { 
    deny all;
   }

 location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
 }

 location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge { 
   allow all; 
 } 
}
```

**Edit**

Does this have anything to do with `501` being the owner and `admin` being the group of all of my Roundcube files except for `logs` & `temp`?

Comment: Please provide the actual configuration of your server, not just a tutorial. We have no way of knowing which steps you followed and which you missed. Also, the first question in this case your be: is the installer directory there?

Comment: You are right, @GeraldSchneider. Give me a moment and I will upload my configurations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, related to my Roundcube log, was because `php7.0-fpm` was not installed! Once I installed it, everything worked fine.